# TVos site shows error "There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website"

Tags: tvos, provisioning-profile

I have a Provisioning Profile for my iOS Development.

I need to add a Provisioning Profile for my tvOS Development.

Here is a litany of snapshots that describe each step of this journey - unfortunately with zero success!

Within Xcode, selected my Target -> Signing and Capabilities:

I get this error:

[image: Xcode Error]

Here are multiple snapshots of Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles within my Developer Account:

[image: Certificates]

[image: Identifiers]

[image: Devices]

When I selected Profiles, I got back **Invalid**, so I deleted the Profile and started from scratch. Here's what eventually showed:

[image: Profiles]

Last, here is what I get when I double-click the above Profile:

[image: Double-click Profile]

What can I try next?

Comment: I have significantly edited my OP, hopefully answering all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

OH MY

Simple Solution that begins with powering up your Apple TV.

Then,

**1)** go to ATV Settings

**2)** -> Remotes and Devices

**3)** -> Remote Apps and Devices

**4)** LEAVE your ATV as is

**5)** return to your iMac and Xcode

**6)** Under Xcode's Window Menu -> Devices and Simulators

**7)** Because your ATV is on, you will see your ATV asking you to Pair Xcode with it. DO SO.

**8)** You will also see the ATV's Identifier (UDID) -- COPY IT

**9)** Go to your Developer Account on your Browser

**10)** -> Devices -> **+** -> Name your Device -> Paste the UDID you just copied

**11)** This magic! happens:

[image: ATV Device Added]

**12)** Return to Xcode and you will see this =

[image: ATV on Xcode]

**13)** Within your Project's Signing and Capabilities, Click button Try Again

**BINGO**